# SQL Server 2008 - code to get prior and future dates

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need to get one previous and one future payment change date, how do I code it in SQL to pull these dates? There are many prior and future change dates but I only want one prior and one future. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like you need `lag()` and `lead()`, but these are not available.

You can do something similar with `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, tprev.changedate, tnext.changedate
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.changedate < t.changedate
      order by tprev.changedate desc
     ) tprev outer apply
     (select top 1 tnext.*
      from t tprev
      where tnext.changedate < t.changedate
      order by tnext.changedate desc
     ) tnext;
```